# ios, quartz2d, fastest way of drawing bitmap context into window context?

Tags: iphone, quartz-graphics

ios, quartz2d, fastest way of drawing bitmap context into window context?

hallo, sorry for my weak english,

I am looking hardly for fastest possible way of redrawing bitmap
context (which holds pointer to may raw bitmap data) onto iphone
view window context

in the examples i have found in the net people are doing this by
making CGImage from such bitmap context then making UIImage
from this and drawing it onto the view

i am thinking if it is a fastest way of doing it? do i need to create
then release CGImage - in documentation there is info that
making CGImage copy data - is it possible to send my bitmap context
data straight to window context without  allocating/ copying then 
releasing it in CGImage? (which seem physically not necessary)

parade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see what you are getting at. You have a pointer to the bitmap data and you just want the window to display that. On the old Mac OS (9 and previous) you could write draw directly to video memory, but you can't do that anymore. Back then video memory was part of RAM and now it's all on the OpenGL card.

At some level the bitmap data will have to be copied at least once. You can either do it directly by creating an OpenGL texture from the data and drawing that in an OpenGL context or you can use the UIImage approach. The UIImage approach will be slower and may contain two or more copies of the bitmap data, once to the UIImage and once when rendering the UIImage.

In either case, you need to create and release the CGImage.

Comment: to Mark Thalman: much tnx for the answer; You know in my app I get the video frame from the iphone camera ("    void *baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);  " speciffically) then

Comment: That video frame is itself a copy from the camera.  Not the copy in the GPU or the copy on the display.  Which are all likely in different formats and arrangements.

Answer (score 1):

Well, i have done some measuring and here is what i have got -

no need to worry about creating CGImage and UIImage stuff becouse it all only takes about 2 miliseconds - my own image processing routines takes the most time (about 100 ms) drawing UIImage at point takes 20 ms - and there is also third thing: when i receive image buffer in my video frame ready delegate i call setNeedsDisplay by performSelectorOnMainThread - and this operation takes sometimes 2 miliseconds and sometimes about 40 miliseconds - does anybody know what it is with that - can i speed up this thing? thanx in advance

parade

Answer (score 0):

The copy is necessary.  You first have to get the bitmap into the GPU, as only the GPU has access to compositing any layer to the display window.  And the GPU has to make a copy into it's opaque (device dependent) format.  One way to do this is to create an image from your bitmap context (other alternatives include uploading an OpenGL texture, etc.)

Once you create an image you can draw it, or assign it to a visible CALayer's contents.  The latter may be faster.

Comment: much tnx for the answers - but if copy is necessary (and it is 'a copy in loop'), do necessary are also continuous malloc()'s and free()'s (and things like  CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(); ) whose i thing are also called every time in loop?

Comment: You can reuse color spaces.  You can reuse bitmap memory as well, but there are some reports that double buffering bitmap memory on some devices results in faster processing times, some of this likely due to CPU data cache flushing and reloading and/or perhaps an MMU copy-on-write memory allocation policy after handing the memory pages to the GPU to copy.

Comment: is CGImage in GPU memory? and what is with making UIImage based on CGImage ( is it 'light' or 'heavy', throwing away UIImage wouldnt not make drawing faster? is release of CGImage after making UIImage from CGImage 'light' or 'heavy')

Comment: This info is probably opaque, and perhaps device and OS version dependent.  You'll have to benchmark each path.  Beware that the various performances have changed significantly with new OS releases (possibly due to GPU driver changes).